# Footnotemark and footnotetext sign are appearing different. How do i resolve this error?

Tags: pdftex, header-footer, footnotes

I have used footnotetext and footnotemark on the title page to include my email and supervisor name. But mark '*' is appearing above while on footer it is showing 1 and 2 as shown in attached image.

How do I get mark 1 and 2 above.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,onecolumn]{article} 

\usepackage{latex8}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,latexsym,epstopdf,array,algorithm,algpseudocode}
\usepackage{adjustbox,lipsum}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxmath,newtxtext}
\usepackage[hmargin=2.25cm,vmargin=2.25cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{enumitem}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\roman{footnote}}

\begin{document}
\title{My title for doctoral competition-2017 \vspace{-3ex}}
\author{Rudresh Dwivedi\footnotemark[1]\footnotemark[2] \ (Enrolled: 2014), Discipline of CSE, Indian Institute of Technology Indore\vspace{-2ex}}
\maketitle
\footnotetext[1]{phd1301201006@iiti.ac.in}
\footnotetext[2]{PhD supervisor: Dr. Somnath Dey}
\vspace{-0.5cm}

Hhhh
Hhh

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty, assuming you want roman numbers and removing some unnecessary things.

```
\documentclass[12pt,onecolumn]{article}
\makeatletter
\let\@fnsymbol\@roman
\makeatother
\title{My title for doctoral competition-2017}
\author{Rudresh Dwivedi\,\thanks{phd1301201006@iiti.ac.in}\,\textsuperscript{,}~\thanks{PhD supervisor: Dr. Somnath Dey}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
Here we go.
\end{document}
```

Replace @roman by @arabic, if needed. Some spacing adjustments will be necessary.